# C++ class does not output correct data?

Tags: c++

No compilation error but the output is this:

g++ class.cpp && ./a.out
is -1003073000 years old.

It does not output the string and int as it supposed to be.

I don't know what is wrong, I would really appreciate if someone point out my mistake, thanks!.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

class Student{
private:
        std::string name;
        int age;
public:
        Student(std::string name, int age){
                name = name;
                age = age;
        }
        void setName(std::string name){
                name = name;
        }
        std::string getName(){
                return name;
        }
        void setAge(int age){
                age = age;
        }
        int getAge(){
                return age;
        }
};

int main(){
        Student student1 = Student("Clayton",20);
        std::cout<<student1.getName();<<" is "<< student1.getAge()<<" years old."<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `name = name;`  should look suspicious to you. Did you mean to use initializer?

Comment: Careful with the variable names. Try using `m_` prefix with members or use initializer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor

```
Student(std::string name, int age){
        name = name;
        age = age;
}
```

The names `name` and `age` are the *argument variables* of those names. Which means you assign the variables to themselves.

That will leave the `Student::name` member default constructed and empty, but the `Student::age` variable will be uninitialized, and have an *indeterminate* value, and using such values (even printing them) is *undefined behavior*.

You have two solutions:

1. Use `this` to explicitly reference the current object and use its member variables:

   ```
   Student(std::string name, int age){
       this->name = name;
       this->age = age;
   }
   ```
2. Or use a member initializer list to initialize (rather than assign to) the member variables:

   ```
   Student(std::string name, int age) : name(name), age(age) {
       // Empty
   }
   ```

   For this the language knows the difference between the member and argument variables.

I highly recommend the second alternative.